# Python - How to make REST POST request

Tags: java, python, rest, post

I have implemented a REST service with Java:

```
@POST
@Path("/policyinjection")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String policyInjection(String request) {

    String queryresult = null;
    String response = null;

    if (request == null) {
        logger.warning("empty request");
    } else {

        //call query() to query redisDB with the request
        queryresult = query(request);

        // call inject() to inject returned policy to floodlight
        response = inject(queryresult);

    }
    return response;
}
```

But I need to use Python to implement the client to make a POST request to the above service.
I am new to python, I want to implement a method do it like this:

```
def callpolicyInjection():
```

Comment: Do you just need to make a POST?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the answer to your *exact* question, but you should take a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.

It allows to send http POST requests (as well as (m)any other http methods) mostly in one line:

```
>>> import requests

>>> keys = {'username':'Sylvain', 'key':'6846135168464431', 'cmd':'do_something'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post",params=keys)
```

---

Now, the answer is in the `r` objects:

```
>>> print(r)
<Response [200]>

>>> print(r.text)
{
  "origin": "70.57.167.19",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?cmd=do_something&key=6846135168464431&username=Sylvain",
  "args": {
    "username": "Sylvain",
    "cmd": "do_something",
    "key": "6846135168464431"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity, gzip, deflate, compress",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/3.3.1 Linux/3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  },
  "json": null,
  "data": ""
}
```

... those are only examples. See requests [response content](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) documentation for details.

Comment: The response is returned by the `response.post(...)` function. I've modified my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `requests` lib. I won't cover this as it has already been answered.

You can also use urllib and urllib2:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

data = {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password'
}

urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/policyinjection/', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

The secode parameter to `urllib2.urlopen` is the data to send along with the request. It is optional, but if you use it your request automatically becomes POST. The advantage of `urllib` over other solutions it that it's part of the standard distribution, so you won't add any extra dependencies to your application.

And if you want performance you should use `pycurl`:

```
import pycurl

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.example.com/policyinjection/')
curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, 'user=username&pass=password')
curl.perform()
```

Unfortunately, `pycurl` is not part of the standard distribution, but you can install it using `pip install pycurl` or `easy_install pycurl`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made [Nap](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap) specifically for this purpose, check it out!

Example usage:

```
from nap.url import Url
api = Url('http://httpbin.org/')

response = api.post('post', data={'test': 'Test POST'})
print(response.json())
```

More examples: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap#examples